# Get records with max sum value of grouped SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table which has three fields like this:

```
PK     account     value
-----------------------
1      40010101    130
1      40010101    500
1      40010569    590
2      40010569    300
2      40010101    200
```

I want to select the record which has highest value of the sum of Value for each PK, grouped by PK and Account, so my result should be like this:

```
PK     account     value
-----------------------
1      40010101    630
2      40010569    300
```

I tried this solution:

```
SELECT
 pn.*
FROM
 (select PK, account, sum(value) as value
 from table
 group by PK, account) pn
INNER JOIN 
 (select PK, MAX(value) AS maxvalue
 from (select PK, account, sum(value) as value
      from table
      group by PK, account) pn 
 group by PK) maxsum
ON pn.PK= maxsum.PK
AND pn.value = maxsum.maxvalue
```

It works, but I ask you a faster solution. I could have thousand of records to match. I can't use a Stored procedure.
Using SQL server.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Can you tag appropriately?

Comment: @Kason You've mistook his question.

Comment: If you provide sqlfiddle.com link for this type of question, it will help us to solve faster and more exact.

Comment: "I want to select the record which has highest value of the sum of Value for each PK" This data set singularly fails to communicate that intent. And that's not a PK. It might be an FK.

Comment: @Strawberry you are right, I simplified the table.
There was another PK2 like an IDENTITY, but i don't need it for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT  PK,
        account, 
        sum_value AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT  PK,
            account, 
            SUM([value]) as sum_value,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PK ORDER BY SUM([value]) DESC) as rn
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY account, PK
) as p
WHERE rn = 1
```

Output:

```
PK  account     value
1   40010101    630
2   40010569    300
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is with a series of joins:

```
SELECT t1.PK, t1.account, t1.value
FROM
(
    SELECT PK, account, SUM(value) AS value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY PK, account
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.PK, MAX(t.value) AS value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT PK, account, SUM(value) AS value
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY PK, account
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.PK
) t2
    ON t1.PK = t2.PK AND t1.value = t2.value
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Use Max without group by?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now is right, but this seems to be similar to the solution with question mentioned. :-(

Comment: MySQL does not have analytic functions, this approach may not be so bad in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query it will work

```
SELECT  pk,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(account ORDER BY val DESC),',',1) AS account,
        MAX(val) AS val 
FROM (
    SELECT  pk,
            account,
            SUM(`value`) AS val  
    FROM test.temp_69 
    GROUP BY pk,account 
    ORDER BY pk
    )  AS t 
GROUP BY pk;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.* FROM 
(
    SELECT PK,account,SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY PK,account
) AS C INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT A.PK, MAX(SUMVALUE) AS MAXVALUE
    FROM TABLE1 AS A INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT PK,account,SUM(VALUE) AS SUMVALUE
        FROM TABLE1
        GROUP BY PK,account

    ) AS B
    ON A.PK = B.PK
    AND A.account = B.account
    GROUP BY A.PK
) AS D
ON C.PK =D.PK
AND C.VALUE = D.MAXVALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

They are essentially equivalent to each other (in fact this is how some databases implement DISTINCT under the hood).

If one of them is faster, it's going to be DISTINCT. This is because, although the two are the same, a query optimizer would have to catch the fact that your GROUP BY is not taking advantage of any group members, just their keys. DISTINCT makes this explicit, so you can get away with a slightly dumber optimizer.

When in doubt, test

Answer (score 0):

do like this using subquery

```
select id,account,max(amount) as value
from 
(
select id,account,sum(value) as amount
from temp_max
group by account,id
order by id
)t
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is definitely a correct one, and easy to understand, it's also not a so bad one, I don't know if there is a better one to get what you want, what I provide you is just do my best to make query to be more simpler, anyway try it.

```
select t.*, if(@pk = `PK`, @rowno := @rowno + 1, @rowno := 1) as vrowno, @pk := `PK` as vpk
from (
    select `PK`, `account`, sum(`value`) as `value`
    from table1
    group by `PK`, `account`
    order by `PK`, `value` desc) t
cross join (select @pk := '', @rowno := 0) v
having vrowno = 1
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1fa50/10)

Hope this will help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer by sub-query and limit 1 in mysql:

```
select PK, account, 
  (select Sum(value) FROM yourTable t2 where t1.PK=t2.PK group by PK,account order by Sum(value) desc limit 1) max_sum
from yourTable t1
where (PK, account)=
  (select PK,account FROM yourTable t2 where t1.PK=t2.PK group by PK,account order by Sum(value) desc limit 1) 
group by PK, account;
```

I don't know its performance is better or not. Please check its performance and inform us.

I provided [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfa6cd/1) link also.